# facing issue when generating provisioning profiles from Jenkins pipeline script

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins

I am facing below issue when generating provisioning profiles from Jenkins pipeline script, please let me know the reason for this.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the issue is not related IOS, its with Jenkins master slave connectivity.
I have setup jenkins master  slave using user name and Private key, in this case XCode commands are not able to connect to internet, but when I setup master slave using username and password, XCode is able to connect to Apple and I am not facing any issue in this case.

But, I need to find why this is not working in case user name and private key.

Thanks,
Raj4MS